# How do I render my blend without Scene Lights and Scene World using HDR lighting?

Tags: rendering, lighting, hdri

I tried to render my keyboard and it renders with Scene World. I tried to change the lighting from Scene World to HDRI (with HDRI it looks good (1)), but then it still ended up a mess.

Where is my mistake, can anyone help me, please?

Viewport, without Scene World or Scene Lights, looks good and I need to render it:
[image]
Render:
[image]

I tried to apply these settings to make all the lighting in the rendering look like the first image (viewport), following advice from the Internet.

[image]

What I got after trying to solve the problem with 3rd Image:
[image]

Where is my mistake, can anyone help me, please?
I just want my rendering to look like the first image (Using HDRI City.exe instead of Scene Lights or World Scene)

Comment: You need to enable *Scene Lights* and *Scene World* to see what the render will give, otherwise you'll see a scene without the effects of your lights and with the effect of one of the default HDRI, not the HDRI you're using in your *World* material, so first thing reactivate these 2 options. If you need to remove your lights because they are too powerful, remove them for real or make them invisible in the *Outliner*. If you need another HDRI, choose another, if you need to make it darker, lower down the *Background* strength value. If it still doesn't fix your problem, share your file

Comment: @moonboots https://dropmefiles.com/6ayRG Tried to follow your advice and background strength helped a little bit, but still, keyboard's lighting too hard on me.

Comment: Oh ok it has to do with your Color Management settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by your *Render > Color Management* settings, switch back to the default ones, at least make sure that it doesn't over-expose your scene (*Exposure* value), here are the default settings (you can right click on the value to reset the value):

[image]

Comment: Big thanks, man! I don't know if I can somehow give you a like or +1 or something like that but thank you!

Comment: Yes actually if the answer is correct you can mark it as correct (check icon on the top left of the answser)  ;)